# Trigger en MySQL para enviar mensajes al celular

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Empiezo con el tema de los triggers y quisiera saber si es posible crear uno que envíe mensajes al celular.

La pregunta ya fue respondida por @Michel Escalante Álvarez.

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende o es demasiado amplia, explica mejor que intentas hacer

Comment: Veo que hay empresas, por ejemplo las de telefonía, que envían mensajes al celular cuando el crédito cargado está a punto de expirar, y quisiera saber si es posible hacer eso mediante triggers o cómo le hacen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no creo que puedas hacer lo que pretendes con triggers, o por lo menos no directamente desde la base de datos. En cualquier caso, puedes crear un trigger que reaccione ante un evento específico en la base de datos (por ejemplo, al insertar una nueva fila en determinada tabla).
Luego, debe existir algún mecanismo que "escuche" el mensaje lanzado por el trigger (digamos, por ejemplo, una aplicación web en PHP conectada a dicha BD) y sea capaz de tomar las acciones necesarias para enviar una notificación a tu celular por la red.
Esa es la idea abstracta de como puedes lograr que que quieres, sin embargo la implementación varía en dependencia de la tecnología que elijas para implementar esto. Saludos